# How can I import a glyph from Lucida Grande into Source Sans Pro for use on the web

Tags: unicode, font-face, webfonts, fontforge

I use the down pointing small triangle symbol (▾ [Unicode 25BE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25be/index.htm)) in a web page, but it is [not supported natively on Motorola / Sony devices](http://unicode.johnholtripley.co.uk/25BE/). Therefore, I want to use a font-face css declaration to load the symbol.

I already use Source Sans Pro on my site, but it doesn't include glyph 25BE. Therefore, I want to patch my Source Sans Pro font file with the 25BE glyph from Lucida Grande (default font used for this symbol in Chrome on OSX).

I tried doing this in FontForge, but the pasted glpyh looks way bigger and differently aligned than in the original font file:

Original Lucida Grande:

[image: Original glyph]

Pasted into Source Sans Pro:

[image: Copied glyph]

Also, when I tried to generate the Source Sans Pro font, I got a load of warnings that I didn't understand.

Is there an easier way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the size difference is the difference of UPM coordinate systems.
SSP is based on 1000 Units per Em, Lucida has 2048.
FontForge obviously does not compensate for the different coordinate systems, that is why the triangles look so much larger after pasting.

Solutions:
– you can try patching SSP with another 1000 UPM-font
– you can use another font for the triangle only
– use a SVG file?